# Working with polymorphic relations in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This one is a little bit tricky for me since it is not covered in documentation at all.

I have four models:

```
App.Dog = DS.Model.extend();
App.Cat = DS.Model.extend();

App.Food = DS.Model.extend();
App.Toy = DS.Model.extend();
```

Both `dog` and `cat` have many `food` and many `toys`. On the other hand a single instance of `food` and `toy` can belong only to one `dog` or `cat` (so it is `hasMany`-ish relation on the animal side and `belongsTo`-ish on the item side).

Any hints how to do this in Ember using polymorphic relations? Or maybe there is a better approach to achieve this other than polymorphic relations?

Also what code should I implement in my controller to create a new `food` or `toy` record that belongs to `dog` or `cat`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this slideshow](http://lukegalea.github.io/ember_data_polymorphic_presentation/#/4), something like:

```
App.Animal = DS.Model.extend({
  food: DS.hasMany('App.Food', { polymorphic: true }),
  toys: DS.hasMany('App.Toy', { polymorphic: true })
});
App.Dog = App.Animal.extend(/* .... */);
App.Cat = App.Animal.extend(/* .... */);

App.Food = DS.Model.extend({
  owner: DS.belongsTo('App.Animal', { polymorphic: true })
});
App.Toy = DS.Model.extend({
  owner: DS.belongsTo('App.Animal', { polymorphic: true })
});
```